# Restarting SQL Server's services remotely programmatically

Tags: sql-server

I have the need to restart Microsoft SQL Server's group of services on a given computer, remotely, through some sort of programmatic method I can insert into a workflow. I'm looking for the best way to do this, I've seen a few different ways and I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing:

- Use `Net Stop` and `Net Start` - This would work if I only needed to restart the SQL Service and there were no dependencies, not really an option if SQL Server Agent is running.
- Use `SC //<computername` This would allow me some access into the `servicecontroller` so I could query whether or not there's a dependent service running.
- Use the .NET `Servicecontroller` method, which would let me build an array of services running on the target computer and then iterate through them to stop what I need to stop.

Am I missing any ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx - you missed for example PowerShell.

Pay extra attention if you're using a clustered instance.

Comment: So many different ways to do the same thing. Since Powershell's a .NET language I could use `servicecontroller` or the `WMI` stuff (as referened there). Definitely a good link though.